# New Pandas Column - Numpy.where with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and I want to to use np.where (numpy) to perform a logical test. My dataframe is `test_df`:

```
    A   B   thing
0   0   0   
1   1   1   
2   2   4   
3   3   9   
4   4   16  
5   5   25  ma
6   6   36  
7   7   49  
8   8   64  
9   9   81
```

I want to create a new column using the np.where with the following conditions:

```
test_list = ['Me', 'ma']
test_df['new_col'] = np.where((test_df['A'] == 0 & test_df['B'] == 0 & test_df['thing'].isin(test_list)) | test_df['B'] == 1, "Yep", "Nope")
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Which stems from `test_df['A'] == 0 & test_df['B'] == 0`. I'm not sure how to resolve this and I'd like to use np.where. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Use parentheses to wrap conditions. Otherwise & takes precedence.`(test_df['A'] == 0) & (test_df['B'] == 0)`

Comment: Saw that answer, just didn't put it together. Thanks!